# Optimizing CLUSTERED INDEX for use with JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, indexing, clustered-index

table `optin_channel_1` (for each 'channel' there's a dedicated table)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[optin_channel_1](
    [key_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [valid_to] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [valid_from] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [key_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [optin_flag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [source_proc_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_inserted] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_id] ON [dbo].[optin_channel_1] 
(
    [key_type_id] ASC,
    [key_id] ASC,
    [valid_to] ASC,
    [valid_from] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

table `profile_conns`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[profile_conns](
    [profile_key_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [valid_to] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [valid_from] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [conn_key_id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [conn_key_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [conn_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [source_proc_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_inserted] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_id] ON [dbo].[profile_conns] 
(
    [profile_key_id] ASC,
    [conn_key_type_id] ASC,
    [conn_key_id] ASC,
    [valid_to] ASC,
    [valid_from] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

table `lu_channel_conns`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lu_channel_conns](
    [channel_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [conn_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lu_channel_conns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [channel_id] ASC,
    [conn_type_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

table `lu_conn_type`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lu_conn_type](
    [conn_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [default_key_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [master_key_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_inserted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_lu_conns] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [conn_type_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

view `v_source_proc_id_by_group_id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.source_proc_id, x.source_proc_group_id
FROM lu_source_proc x INNER JOIN lu_source_proc_group y ON x.source_proc_group_id = y.group_id
```

There's a dynamic SQL statement going to be executed:

```
SET @sql_str='SELECT @ret=MAX(o.optin_flag)
    FROM optin_channel_'+CAST(@channel_id AS NVARCHAR(100))+' o
    INNER HASH JOIN dbo.v_source_proc_id_by_group_id y ON o.source_proc_id=y.source_proc_id AND y.source_proc_group_id=@source_proc_group_id
    INNER HASH JOIN profile_conns z ON z.profile_key_id=cast(@profile_key_id AS NVARCHAR(100)) AND z.conn_key_type_id=o.key_type_id AND z.conn_key_id=o.[key_id] AND z.valid_to=''01.01.3000''
    INNER HASH JOIN lu_channel_conns x ON x.channel_id=@channel_id AND z.conn_type_id=x.conn_type_id
    INNER HASH JOIN lu_conn_type ct ON ct.conn_type_id=x.conn_type_id AND ct.default_key_type_id=o.key_type_id'
SET @param='@channel_id INT, @profile_key_id INT, @source_proc_group_id INT, @ret NVARCHAR(400) OUTPUT'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_str,@param,@channel_id,@profile_key_id,@source_proc_group_id,@ret OUTPUT
```

I.e. this gives:

```
SELECT @ret=MAX(o.optin_flag) AS optin_flag
FROM optin_channel_1 o
INNER HASH JOIN dbo.v_source_proc_id_by_group_id y 
    ON o.source_proc_id=y.source_proc_id 
    AND y.source_proc_group_id=5
INNER HASH JOIN profile_conns z 
    ON z.profile_key_id=1 
    AND z.conn_key_type_id=o.key_type_id 
    AND z.conn_key_id=o.[key_id] 
    AND z.valid_to='01.01.3000'
INNER HASH JOIN lu_channel_conns x 
    ON x.channel_id=1 
    AND z.conn_type_id=x.conn_type_id
INNER HASH JOIN lu_conn_type ct 
    ON ct.conn_type_id=x.conn_type_id 
    AND ct.default_key_type_id=o.key_type_id
```

These tables are used for an optin database. `optin_flag` could be 0 or 1. With the last statement I want to get a 1 as `optin_flag` from `optin_channel_1` for the given `channel_id=1` for user with `profile_key_id=1`, when optin was inserted into database by process belonging to `source_proc_group_id=5`. I hope this is enough to comprehend what's going on.

Is this the best way to use the `CLUSTERED INDEX`'es? Or would it be better to remove `profile_key_id` from index on `profile_conns` and put `z.profile_key_id=1` in a `WHERE` clause?

May be there's a much better way for optimizing this select (changes in database schema is not possible, only changes on indexes and modifing statement).

Comment: Are you having performance issues with the current method or do you **think you will have** potential performance issues?

Comment: We only have planned to do some intensive tests in future. This dynamic SQL is only part of a huge trigger on a table and when the trigger runs, this part consumes more than 50% of complete time, because this statement runs 30 times for 30 channels. I expect a run time of the trigger of 200-300ms. But now it runs about a second. Sure you don't know the rest of the trigger, but above SQL takes the most time, so I think it should be optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the size of the tables and the sort of data stored in it them it is difficult to gauge.

Assuming optin_channel_1 has a lot of data and profile_cons has a lot of data I would try the following:

- Clustered index on optin_channel_1(key_id) or key_type_id depending on which field has the most distinct values. (since you don't have a covering index)
- Clustered index on profile_conns (cons_key_id) or cons_key_type_id depending on what you have chosen in optin_channel_1
- etc...

Basically, if your table profile_conns table has not much data, I would put the clustered index on the most fragmented "filter" field (I suspect profile_key_id). If the table has a lot of data I would aim for a hash/merge join and match the clustered index with the clustered index of the optin_channel_1 table.

I would also rewrite the query as such:

```
SELECT @ret = MAX(o.optin_flag) AS optin_flag
  FROM optin_channel_1 o
  JOIN dbo.v_source_proc_id_by_group_id y 
    ON o.source_proc_id = y.source_proc_id  
  JOIN profile_conns z 
    ON z.conn_key_type_id = o.key_type_id 
   AND z.conn_key_id = o.[key_id] 
  JOIN lu_channel_conns x 
    ON z.conn_type_id = x.conn_type_id
  JOIN lu_conn_type ct 
    ON ct.conn_type_id = x.conn_type_id 
   AND ct.default_key_type_id=o.key_type_id 
 WHERE y.source_proc_group_id = 5
   AND z.profile_key_id = 1 
   AND x.channel_id = 1 
   AND z.valid_to = '01.01.3000'
```

The query changed this way because:

- Putting the filter conditions in the where clause shows you what are relevant fields to aim for a hash/merge join
- Putting join hints is rarely a good idea. It is very hard to beat the query governor to determine the best query plan. A bad plan usually indicates you have an issue with your indexes/statistics.

So as summary:

- small table joined to big table ==> go for nested loops & focus your clustered index on the "filter" field in the small table & the join field in the big table.
- big table joined to big table => go for hash/merge join and put the clustered index on the matching field on both sides
- multi-field indexes usually only a good idea when they are "covering", this means all the fields you query are included in the index. (or are included with the include() clause)

Comment: +1 For removing the `JOIN` hint and moving filters to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: My experience is that putting the condition in the join can SOMETIMES result in better performance. In one of the databases I developed there are a join tables for multi-value (e.g. the cc list on an email) with over 100 million records and the main table has about 1 million.   If the query condition on the join filters the 100 million record table down to 100 records then performing the filter prior to the join resulted in much better performance. SQL was better about doing that filter prior to the join if the condition was in the join and I could not get that effect with table hints.

Comment: @BalamBalam That sounds like incorrect statistics leading to a bad query plan. The query governor makes the exact same query plan as far as I know. I will run a number of tests this weekend to double check.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the time, I'll go for testing next week. You're right, the big tables are `optin_channel_1` and `profile_conns` (nearly the same size). As you mention the clustered index should be on `key_type_id` and `key_id` because these columns belong to the join. My idea was to put also `profile_key_id` in clustered index on `profile_conns` because there are also lots of `SELECT`s on this table, which filter in `WHERE` on this field

Comment: only if the selects also filter on the key_id and key_type_id it will have any use to put the profile_key_id in.

Comment: @Filip De Vos should the other keys really be in `WHERE` clause of `SELECT`? The `profile_key_id` is the first field in clustered index.

Comment: There is no obligation to put the "filter" fields in the where clause. I just find it a good practice.